# New Acer Nitro 5 with Ubuntu 16.04 show No space available 0.0KB

Tags: 16.04, system-installation, hard-drive, acer

I tried to set up new Acer Nitro 5 with a new installation of Ubuntu 16.04, but no storage space shows up.

Motherboard information:

[image: Main Board Information]

Error message:

[image: Error Message]

Answer (score 0):

Storage Scheme got to change from SATA RSI to AHCI and for Acer you could achieve such a by reference
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2439670